# Show button only if user belongs to post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

Everything I've searched for here has yet to work. I'm sure its easy but I'm still very much in the learning process here. I want the delete button to show ONLY if the logged in user created the pit. I don't see why I can't use the same code I've been using to show everything else above. I have

```
<p>Pit Created by: <%= link_to pit.user.name, current_user %> on <%= pit.created_at %></p>
            <% if current_user == @pit.user? %>
            <%= link_to "View Pit", '#', class: "btn btn-primary" %>
            <%= link_to 'Delete Pit', [pit],
                 method: :delete,
                 data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
                 <% else %>
            <%= link_to "View Pit", '#', class: "btn btn-primary" %>
            <% end %>
```

I'm getting

```
undefined method `user?
```

Pits Controller

```
class PitsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :current_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy

def new
  @pit = Pit.new
end

def index
  @pit = Pit.all
  @user = User.find_by(params[:id])
  @pits = Pit.paginate(:page => params[:page]).order('created_at ASC').group_by { |pit| pit.created_at.strftime("%B %Y") }
end




    def create
      @user = current_user
      @pit = current_user.pits.create(pit_params)
        if @pit.save
          flash[:success] = "Pit Created!"
          redirect_to @pit
        else
          render 'new'
        end
    end



    def show
      @pit = Pit.find(params[:id])
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
       @pit = Pit.find(pit_params[:id])
         if @pit.update_attributes(pit_params)
           redirect_to @pit
         end
    end

    def destroy
      @pit = Pit.find(params[:id])
      @pit.destroy
      redirect_to pits_path
    end

    def upvote
      @pit = Pit.find(params[:pit_id])
      @pit.upvote_from current_user
      redirect_to pit_path(@pit)
    end

    def downvote
      @pit = Pit.find(params[:pit_id])
      @pit.downvote_from current_user
      redirect_to pit_path(@pit)
    end


    private

    def correct_user
        @pit = current_user.pits.find_by_id(params[:id])
        redirect_to root_path if @pit.nil?
      end

    def pit_params
        params.require(:pit).permit(:topic, :summary, :image, :video_url, :author, :user_id)
    end

    end
```

I've tried a few different combinations to get it to work but nothing has worked yet. Would love some suggestions.Thanks.

Comment: if you use, user? method you should define that, in any controller or in helper..

Comment: better try like this <% if current_user.id == @pit.user.id %> and make sure your having one to one association between pit and user models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> undefined method `user?

This error means you don't have the method `user?` for your `User` object. You could fix this by creating a method in your `User` model to identify the user, but I think what you're *really* trying to do is to [authorize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authorization) the user

A simple remedy for this would be as follows:

```
<% if current_user.id == @pit.user.id %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

---

**Index**

I did notice that your `@pit` variable is being called as the following:

```
def index
   @pit = Pit.all
end
```

You have to appreciate that this will be a big problem if you're trying to call it for specific instances of `Pit`. The `all` method returns a *collection* of data from your db - meaning that if you're trying to call `@pit.user`, it will fail.

If you're going to use a collection, you'll be best doing the following:

```
<% @pit.each do |pit| %>
   <%= link_to pit.name, pit %>
   <%= link_to pit.name, pit, method: :delete, if can? :destroy, pit %>
<% end %>
```

---

**Authorization**

What you're looking for is specifically called [authorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authorization) (as opposed to authentication, which is to identify users).

Authorization is there to *authorize* (grant permission) to users who have credentials enough to warrant a particular action. This is covered in depth with [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan):

[image]

It must be noted that the author of RailsCasts, Ryan Bates (who's on sabbatical somewhere) created a gem for this exact reason -- [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan)

---

**CanCanCan**

I've not used CanCan a lot - I'll try and describe how to use it here. By the way, because Ryan Bates is on leave, an upgraded version of the gem, called [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) has now been published, which I believe to be actively maintained

*1. Ability*

The CanCanCan gem basically works by defining a series of "abilities" for users, allowing you to then "reference" these abilities through the user of the `can?` method:

You can generate the following:

```
> rails g cancan:ability

#app/models/ability.rb
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, :all
    end
  end
end
```

*2. Can?*

Once you have defined abilities, you'll then be able to [call the `can?` method](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan#2-check-abilities--authorization) on the object you with to authorize. This means you'll be able to do this:

```
<%= link_to "View Pit", '#', class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<%= link_to "Delete", @pit, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" } if can? :destroy, @pit %>
```

A much more extensible solution for you!!

Comment: Thanks Rich. That was quite extensive and very helpful. The amount of help on here amongst the ruby community never ceases to amaze me. I've heard about cancan but just have yet to use it. Now that you've explained it seems I may. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This line     `current_user == @pit.user?` is not working because you did not define `user?` method anywhere. `==` sign already means that you check the equality (and will return `true` or `false`).

And generally it is better to check association by some attribute (`id` would be better solution in this case):

```
if @pit.user.id == current_user.id
```

would be something you are looking for.

Comment: So my Index in pits controller above does not accomplish define @user? I'm still learning this stuff so its a bit confusing at times.

Comment: it accomplishes to define `@user`. But `@user` and `@user?` are two different things :)

Comment: Hey thanks andrey for the prompt replies. I think I may go with the more extensive response above but you were helpful.

Comment: Yea, @Rich Peck is always best in explanations, this is absolute true :) good luck!